# Making jQuery tooltip disappear after 2 seconds

Tags: jquery

I am looking to make my jQuery tooltip to disappear after 2 seconds. I am using the following code below but it only disappears after I mouse out. I want it to disappear 2 seconds after it opens.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".name" ).tooltip({ hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 2000 } });

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **setTimeout**

Here I will show one simple example ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").mouseover(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
 setTimeout (function(){$("p").css("background-color","lightgray");},1000);
  });
  $("p").mouseout(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color","red");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Move the mouse pointer over this paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope it will help you ! Thank you !!!

Comment: Welcome ! If its OK ; then tick this as your answer !Thank you